# How to declare two functions taking each other's signature as argument?

Tags: c++, boost, argument-passing, function-signature

Is it possible to emulate something like this:

```
typedef boost::function<void(A)> B;
typedef boost::function<void(B)> A;
```

The main goal is to be able to write code like this (in pseudo-c++):

```
void a_(B b) {
  // ...
  b(a_);
}
void b_(A a) {
  // ...
  f(boost::bind(a, b_));
}

f(boost::bind(a_, b_));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly possible with typedefs; wherever a typedef is used, it is *equivalent* to the original type, so if you write

```
typedef boost::function<void(A)> B;
typedef boost::function<void(B)> A;
```

then `B` would be equivalent to `boost::function<void(A)>`, 
which is equivalent to `boost::function<void(boost::function<void(B)>)>`, and so on, until you get

```
boost::function<void(boost::function<void(boost::function<void(...)>)>)>
```

, which is a type of infinite length.

You can, however, define (at least) one of the two types as a `struct` or `class`:

```
struct A;
typedef boost::function<void(A)> B;
struct A
{
    B b;
    A(B b) : b(b) {}

    // optional:
    void operator() (A a) { b(a); }
};
```

You might need to add more constructors and/or a conversion operator to make the type behave completely "transparently", or you could just access the struct explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not technically precise. A signature is not something you pass as argument. I try my best to make sense of your question.

The following function objects can be passed as argument to each other

```
struct foo { 
  template<typename T> void operator()(T);
};

struct bar {
  template<typename T> void operator()(T);
};

foo f; bar b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using function pointers?

```
#include <iostream>

  // void (*functionPtr)() <- declaration of function pointer
void f(void (*functionPtr)()) {
  // execute the function that functionPtr points to
  (*functionPtr)();
}

void a() {
  std::cout << "Function a()" << std::endl; 
}

int main() {
  f(a);
}
```

I've made that sample code and it works. Maybe you could use it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve what you described by passing these functions to each other just as `void*`. Maybe it's not the nicest way, but it works (I tested it).

```
typedef void (*A)(void*);
typedef void (*B)(void*);

void afun(void* _bf) {
    B _bfun = (B)_bf;
    _bfun((void*)afun);
}

void bfun(void* _af) {
    A _afun = (A)_af;
    f(boost::bind(_afun, (void*)bfun));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    f(boost::bind(afun, (void*)bfun));
    return 0;
}
```